# Reactjs history push doesn't work in drawer component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**App.js**

```js
import React from "react";

import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "../src/history";


// Redux
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";


function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Provider store={store().store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={store().persistor}>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <NavBar />
          <Drawer />
          <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Login}></Route>
              <Route path="/country" exact component={Country}></Route>
              <Route path="/user-create" exact component={User}></Route>
              <Route path="/countries" exact component={ListView}></Route>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

// export default connect() (App);
export default App;
```

**History.js**

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

**Drawers.js**

```js
import history from '../../history'


function TemporaryDrawer(props) {
 
  

  

  const onRoute = (path) => {
   
    history.push(path);
    
  }
    /......... other codes

  
  
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { isDrawerOpen: state.auth.isDrawerOpen, token: state.auth.token };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { toggleDrawer })(TemporaryDrawer);
```

In Drawer component I want to change the route. When I hit on route method, I can see the route name is changing in the web browser URL. But it won't render the component in the Browser. If I refresh the page, then it will render the page. Why could this happen?

Comment: why are you importing `history`? Doesn't `react-router` give you history from one of their hooks?

Comment: can you post your code to stackblitz ?

Comment: Can you give an example of route which is not working? Is `/countries/drawer` route not working?

Comment: @AjeetShah I think it always push to the not found component. I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63563203/react-router-history-push-always-route-to-404-page

Comment: @KhanhLeTran I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63563203/react-router-history-push-always-route-to-404-page

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá I can't use useHistory hook. history prop is doesn't pass to the Drawer.js