# React router history push always route to 404 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

js and facing hard time with react router dom.
I want to change the route when I click a button in my navigation drawer component.

This is my **App.js** component.

```js
import {  Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <NavBar />
          <Drawer />
          <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Login}></Route>
              <Route path="/country" exact component={Country}></Route>
              <Route path="/user-create" exact component={User}></Route>
              <Route path="/countries" exact component={ListView}></Route>
              <Route component={NotFound}></Route>

            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
     
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

And here I pass history prop to the Router component.
**History.js**

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

**Drawer.js**

```
import history from '../../history'

 const onRoute = (path) => {
    
    history.push("/user-create");
    // props.toggleDrawer();
  }
```

**In Drawer.js it is always route to the NotFoundComponet.**
Why could this happen?

Comment: Try wrapping your Drawer component inside the Router !

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS You mean create a new route for drawer?

Comment: @ Pathum, nope just move the Router above Drawer component, Wrap the Drawer component also with Router, a try

Comment: Everything seems correct. Are you really doing `history.push("/user-create");` or `history.push(path);`? `NotFoundComponet` will be rendered when `path` takes a value other than - `/`, `/country`, `/user-create` or `/countries`.

Comment: Can you post a minimal, reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your NavBar and Drawer components include the below withRouter or the alt useHistory hook to get access to the history prop.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
...
this.props.history.push('/user-create')
...
export default withRouter(...
```

Comment: There's no need to `withRouter`, OP is importing the `history`  object in the `Drawer` component.

Comment: @Yousaf It works and I import {BrowserRouter as Router}. I think with that this thing works.

Comment: @PathumKalhan it works because instead of using the `history` object imported explicitly, you are using the `history` object passed as a prop because of `withRouter` higher order component BUT importing the `history` object like you are in the `Drawer` component should also work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put `<NavBar />` and `<Drawer />` inside `<Router>`, and do

```js
const { push } = useHistory()   // from react-router-dom
```

inside them, to get a reference of the `push` API